# Track from which computers a file has been saved

Tags: filesystems, file-management, file-descriptors

Is there any way to track from which computer (username) a certain file has been modified? From `right click > Properties > Details` you can see the creator of the file, but I would like to see who has "save" the file.

I am a teacher, and this would be good for me to avoid fraud in computer-based exams.

Linux or Windows solutions are welcome

Comment: What software is used to edit the file?

Comment: If your school has a Windows Server, you can enable the Audit function for going forward to know who is using files / folders.

Comment: @harrymc I currently teach programming classes, so they are code files (usually .ipynb or .py) that the students edit each one with the editor of their choice (usually VS code or Pycharm). But if this were possible only for certain types of files (e.g. doc, pdf, etc), I could think about adapting the type of exam.

Comment: How are the files presented to you? Email, cloud storage or what?

Comment: This is flexible. I usually ask them to email me the file, but it could also be done through our Learning Management System, or other new ways

Comment: You are aware that, these fields, can be modified and you would not know it right? Why don't you just compare the files to one another? There are tools to do that in your field I am sure. The meta data that File Explorer can display for those particular file extensions will not display the information what you want. Even if they did, the information can be modified or cleared any number of ways, and you wouldn't be able to tell the reason they were wiped (or tell if they were modified). There are tools to modify the fields.

Answer (score 1):

For Word, you may have a look at the menu *File > Info*.

You will see there the name of the author, as well as the
"Last Modified By".

This meta-data can be removed, but removing it is already a signal
that there was something to hide.

Comment: I submitted hundreds of documents for my multiple degrees, I nearly always wiped the personal information from that document, since the author information could be nearly anything depending on what system I was using at the time.  If I was logged into a system on campus, it would indicate one thing, while my personal computer(s) would indicate a different author.  There are better ways to determine if I plagiarized a document then looking at the author of a Word document, which can modified, to be whatever you want. I can't get behind the "something to hide" comment.

Comment: Programs are pretty easy to verify, by comparing the errors or inefficiencies. One can find not only copies but also cases where students worked together without wholesale copying. This requires examining the programs, not only their results. All other methods are easily falsifiable, especially for people with some computer knowledge.

Comment: I can edit a file you author and make it appear I author it, and somebody who didn't see the original file, couldn't tell the difference between the two file other than who authored it..

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to a certain extent to tell which user created a file *but* it is also trivial to circumvent (just copy and paste the contents instead of the file). Furthermore, this metadata (which is not part of the file data) is lost when copying to certain filesystems (exFAT and FAT32 are of special relevance, used on many USB flash drives) and may also be changed when copying to remote systems.

It also is not carried on e-mails or file uploads to the web.

This is not information you can use to reliably detect or rule out cheating/plagiarism.

Some file types have metadata embedded (like MS Office documents), but they, too, are not usable as proof, but as a clue at best.

Comment: As you point out. I can wipe the meta data of a Word document before I submit it, and anyone viewing that document, wouldn't be able to identify that I did that.  Certainly, if I then added that information back into the meta data before I submitted the document. I can take just the meta data that File Explorer and clear that, as you say, by just copying it to a FAT32 volume and uploading that copy instead of the copy that exists on a volume with that meta data.  I can also programmatically modify the data.